# How do I create a wx.Image object from in-memory data?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a GUI application in Python using wxPython and I want to display an image in a static control (`wx.StaticBitmap`).

I can use [`wx.ImageFromStream`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#ImageFromStream) to load an image from a file, and this works OK:

```
static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(parent, wx.ID_ANY)
f = open("test.jpg", "rb")
image = wx.ImageFromStream(f)
bitmap = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)
static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
```

But, what I really want to be able to do is create the image from data in memory. So, if I write

```
f = open("test.jpg", "rb")
data = f.read()
```

how can I create a `wx.Image` object from `data`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use `StringIO` to wrap the buffer in a memory file object.

```
...
import StringIO

buf = open("test.jpg", "rb").read()
# buf = get_image_data()
sbuf = StringIO.StringIO(buf)

image = wx.ImageFromStream(sbuf)
...
```

`buf` can be replaced with any data string.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Python you use Duck Typing you can write your own stream class and hand an instance of that class to ImageFromStream. I think you only need to implement the read method and make it return your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you the python3.x ,you should use "ByteIO" and "ImageFromStream" to display the picture data from memory. Attention, the format of the parameter of "BytesIO" should be b"\xff\xd8"
The following is the picture to show the code:
[the format of the parameter of the BytesIO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwNBA.png)