# How to convert images as python code

Tags: python, listview, wxpython, listviewitem, objectlistview

I have been tried to make application with wxpython. I needed to make listview for my GUI(facebook loading). So I choose the ObjectListview. Unfortunately It is very hard work and lack of info for beginner. I tested 'SimpleExamples'. It works great. but I need to change the image. Despite all my efforts to figure out by myself, I couldn't. From some efforts, I found out that images file as python code. But I don't know how to convert images as python code

Can you help me??? Your answer could be my best answer.

source code from     https://github.com/adrianer/ObjectListView

Here is SimpleExample2.py from ObjectListview

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import wx

# Where can we find the ObjectListView module?
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

import ExampleModel
import ExampleImages ******# We store our images as python code**Look at here please~****

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.Init()

    def Init(self):
        self.InitModel()
        self.InitWidgets()
        self.InitObjectListView()

    def InitModel(self):
        self.songs = ExampleModel.GetTracks()

    def InitWidgets(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(panel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.myOlv = ObjectListView(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.myOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 4)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer_2)

        self.Layout()

    def InitObjectListView(self):
        groupImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ExampleImages.getGroup16Bitmap(), ExampleImages.getGroup32Bitmap())
        userImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ExampleImages.getUser16Bitmap(), ExampleImages.getUser32Bitmap())
        musicImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ExampleImages.getMusic16Bitmap(), ExampleImages.getMusic32Bitmap())

        soloArtists = ["Nelly Furtado", "Missy Higgins", "Moby", "Natalie Imbruglia",
                       "Dido", "Paul Simon", "Bruce Cockburn"]
        def artistImageGetter(track):
            if track.artist in soloArtists:
                return userImage
            else:
                return groupImage

        def sizeToNiceString(byteCount):
            """
            Convert the given byteCount into a string like: 9.9bytes/KB/MB/GB
            """
            for (cutoff, label) in [(1024*1024*1024, "GB"), (1024*1024, "MB"), (1024, "KB")]:
                if byteCount >= cutoff:
                    return "%.1f %s" % (byteCount * 1.0 / cutoff, label)

            if byteCount == 1:
                return "1 byte"
            else:
                return "%d bytes" % byteCount

        self.myOlv.SetColumns([
            ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 120, "title", imageGetter=musicImage),
            ColumnDefn("Artist", "left", 120, "artist", imageGetter=artistImageGetter),
            ColumnDefn("Size", "center", 100, "sizeInBytes", stringConverter=sizeToNiceString),
            ColumnDefn("Last Played", "left", 100, "lastPlayed", stringConverter="%d-%m-%Y"),
            ColumnDefn("Rating", "center", 100, "rating")
        ])
        self.myOlv.SetObjects(self.songs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(1)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "ObjectListView Simple Example 2")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And there is the ExampleImages.py code
I never seen those code(x00\x10\x08). I think that if I want to use image in Objectlistview, I need to change the code something like this(x00\x10\x08).

```
from wx import ImageFromStream, BitmapFromImage, EmptyIcon
import cStringIO, zlib


def getGroup16Data():
    return zlib.decompress(
'x\xda\x017\x01\xc8\xfe\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\
\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x90\x91h6\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\
\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xefIDAT(\x91\x85\x92\xc1u\xc30\x0cC\x117Sh\rt\
\r\xadA\xceD\xcc\x9150G\xc7P\x0f\xb2]5\xcf\xcf\xc1I\x96\xf8\x01\x89\xe6c\x8c\
\x01@\x92m\x00U\x85{\x8d1\xaaj\x8c1\xc6\x88\x88\x88\x18\x87\xaaj\xfd\x9c\xda\
&v&\x9c\x92\x14\x11$3s\xdd\xdfl\x03\x94\x9c\x99+2y\x92oF_\x00z\x8f\xde{kA\
\xf6\xd6\xba\x94\xad5+\x7f\xd0^\xafWk\xad\xf7\xfe\x97p\xaeH\x90\x98vRV\x85\
\x95\xb0\xc2\xca\xfc>\xcb\x9ek\xdc\x12n\xd8U\x01\x00\x16\xe4k\xe0]\xd6d\xff=\
\xba\xaa\xa4\xa5\x0fRD\xdc\x98l\x87\xd7\xbc\xbb\xbd\x1b\xf2\x03\xb0c$\x08I+`\
\x03\x8ck`)\xf2^\xea\xd9:K\x9aG\xb7\x8f\x9eW\xf3n\x91\x99$\x8f\xd1\xb0>\x90G\
\xf2\x13\xc7\x84f\xa6$\x92\xf6\xc5D\xecy\xe4c\x8e\xf7\xd49gUe[\xca\xfd_2H\
\xcev\xff\x02\x0b[\xa5cP|\xd5p\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\xf3\x99\x84Y' )

def getGroup16Bitmap():
    return BitmapFromImage(getGroup16Image())

def getGroup16Image():
    stream = cStringIO.StringIO(getGroup16Data())
    return ImageFromStream(stream)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I wrong understood???
Is there any other way to change the image.
(I need to change the image size, position, fonts and size of text etc.... but First I want to change images)

Comment: _"I found out that images file as python code."_ What does this mean? The only meaning of "file" as a verb that I know of is "to organize in a filing cabinet" and that doesn't seem to make sense in context here.

Comment: @Kevin : I mean that to change the image to python code something like this(x\xda\x017\x01\xc8\xfe\x). From those code(SimpleExamples to use), I need to change the image as python code

Comment: @Kevin : (where is your another comment?... It was here... anyway, from your missing comment)  I replaced some like this. but.... It doesn't work. Can you give me some advice about it?      
        buf = open("1.png", "rb").read()
        # buf = get_image_data()
        sbuf = StringIO.StringIO(ssbut)
        musicImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ImageFromStre1am(sbuf))

Comment: @Kevin http://kalten.tistory.com/53   here is changing code. but I doesn't work. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375820/how-do-i-create-a-wx-image-object-from-in-memory-data     this is the code that I referenced. Thank U~~

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach to embedding and image in a python file with wxPython is to use [img2py](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.tools.img2py-module.html).  [Here's](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/23/wxpython-embedding-an-image-in-your-title-bar/) a blog post that uses it (see about half way down).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
from wx import BitmapFromImage, ImageFromStream
from cStringIO import StringIO

def getGroup16Data():
    return \
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\
\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x90\x91h6\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\
\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xefIDAT(\x91\x85\x92\xc1u\xc30\x0cC\x117Sh\rt\
\r\xadA\xceD\xcc\x9150G\xc7P\x0f\xb2]5\xcf\xcf\xc1I\x96\xf8\x01\x89\xe6c\x8c\
\x01@\x92m\x00U\x85{\x8d1\xaaj\x8c1\xc6\x88\x88\x88\x18\x87\xaaj\xfd\x9c\xda\
&v&\x9c\x92\x14\x11$3s\xdd\xdfl\x03\x94\x9c\x99+2y\x92oF_\x00z\x8f\xde{kA\
\xf6\xd6\xba\x94\xad5+\x7f\xd0^\xafWk\xad\xf7\xfe\x97p\xaeH\x90\x98vRV\x85\
\x95\xb0\xc2\xca\xfc>\xcb\x9ek\xdc\x12n\xd8U\x01\x00\x16\xe4k\xe0]\xd6d\xff=\
\xba\xaa\xa4\xa5\x0fRD\xdc\x98l\x87\xd7\xbc\xbb\xbd\x1b\xf2\x03\xb0c$\x08I+`\
\x03\x8ck`)\xf2^\xea\xd9:K\x9aG\xb7\x8f\x9eW\xf3n\x91\x99$\x8f\xd1\xb0>\x90G\
\xf2\x13\xc7\x84f\xa6$\x92\xf6\xc5D\xecy\xe4c\x8e\xf7\xd49gUe[\xca\xfd_2H\
\xcev\xff\x02\x0b[\xa5cP|\xd5p\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82\xf3\x99\x84Y'

def getGroup16Bitmap():
    return BitmapFromImage(ImageFromStream(StringIO(getGroup16Data())))
```

To convert the image use the code from:  [Create text file of hexadecimal from binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219670/create-text-file-of-hexadecimal-from-binary/45345350#45345350)
Please check that I left off the starting part of your hexadecimal string leaving the part from `'\x89PNG...'`.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found out^^
It works. but Objectlistview is not easy at all.... I need to find to change the fonds and size more and more. anyway here is the code

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import datetime
    import wx
    import cStringIO
    from PIL import Image

    #from wx import ImageFromStream, BitmapFromImage, EmptyIcon

    # Where can we find the ObjectListView module?
    import sys
    sys.path.append("..")

    from ObjectListView import ObjectListView, ColumnDefn

    import ExampleModel
    import ExampleImages # We store our images as python code

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
            self.Init()

        def Init(self):
            self.InitModel()
            self.InitWidgets()
            self.InitObjectListView()

        def InitModel(self):
            self.songs = ExampleModel.GetTracks()

        def InitWidgets(self):
            panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
            sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer_1.Add(panel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
            self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

            self.myOlv = ObjectListView(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
            sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer_2.Add(self.myOlv, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 4)
            panel.SetSizer(sizer_2)

            self.Layout()

        def InitObjectListView(self):
            groupImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ExampleImages.getGroup16Bitmap(), ExampleImages.getGroup32Bitmap())
            userImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(ExampleImages.getUser16Bitmap(), ExampleImages.getUser32Bitmap())
    ######################################################################3333
            #open the image file
            imageFile = '111.png'
            data = open(imageFile, "rb").read()
            # convert to a data stream
            stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
            # convert to a bitmap
            bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage( wx.ImageFromStream(stream))
            musicImage = self.myOlv.AddImages(bmp)
   ###################################################################
   #########  changed code  ##########################################

            soloArtists = ["Nelly Furtado", "Missy Higgins", "Moby", "Natalie Imbruglia",
                           "Dido", "Paul Simon", "Bruce Cockburn"]

            def artistImageGetter(track):
                if track.artist in soloArtists:
                    return userImage
                else:
                    return groupImage

            def sizeToNiceString(byteCount):
                """
                Convert the given byteCount into a string like: 9.9bytes/KB/MB/GB
                """
                for (cutoff, label) in [(1024*1024*1024, "GB"), (1024*1024, "MB"), (1024, "KB")]:
                    if byteCount >= cutoff:
                        return "%.1f %s" % (byteCount * 1.0 / cutoff, label)

                if byteCount == 1:
                    return "1 byte"
                else:
                    return "%d bytes" % byteCount

            self.myOlv.SetColumns([
                ColumnDefn("Title", "left", 120, "title", imageGetter=musicImage),
                ColumnDefn("Artist", "left", 120, "artist", imageGetter=artistImageGetter),
                ColumnDefn("Size", "center", 100, "sizeInBytes", stringConverter=sizeToNiceString),
                ColumnDefn("Last Played", "left", 100, "lastPlayed", stringConverter="%d-%m-%Y"),
                ColumnDefn("Rating", "center", 100, "rating")
            ])
            self.myOlv.SetObjects(self.songs)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.PySimpleApp(1)
        wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
        frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, "ObjectListView Simple Example 2")
        app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
        frame_1.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It is helpful to explain **what you have changed** and, if at all possible, **why**.